# Error handling in properties, I know its bad, need fix though

Tags: c#, error-handling, coding-style

I know its bad practice to put error handling in properties I just want to know *where* I should be putting the error handling. I know that a value in a property should never change.

I have a gridview where the user is allowed to change cell 2 to any value (char) but if the user enters something larger than a char it will populate an error, is my best bet to just check on the gridview somehow?

I seem to run into this problem a bit, when I have properties or even methods that return a type, I can't get into error handling, without doing a try catch (or TryParse) and if its wrong returning the type but blank.

```
public char WeightClass
{
   get
      {
         return Convert.ToChar(gvFighters.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[2].Value);
      }
}
```

EDIT: if you could provide some additional readings for code practices that would also be a plus read most of code complete....

**EDIT**

```
   public char FlightClassFromRow()
            {   
                char result;
                if(Char.TryParse(gvSegments.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),out result))
                {
                    return result;
                }
     //if false, return empty char? is that the best way?
            }
```

Comment: Personally, as a rule, if the property call involves any kind of method call that could error, then I make the property a method. Properties should always return, unless the object is in an invalid state (for whatever reason)

Comment: Convert.ToChar won't throw an exception if the string-length is greater than 1. Instead it only uses the first char of the string.
You should add a CompareValidator(or CustomValidator if it's not as easy) to your cell and validate a TextBox. You could both add in GridView's RowCreated event-handler.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts I have edited it to a method, but I still have to return a char.. but I don't want to return a blank char, as I would have to do another check on it...but is that the only way?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a try catch.

- Check if your row- & columnnumbers are smaller then the row/column count
- Use Char.TryParse

But if a property is doing more than a simple return it's better to just use a method.

Comment: okay I have edited to a method, it seems I still have to return something, I can't just throw a msgbox...

Comment: You have multiple options. Use an enum with values and add one "empty" enum. Use one characters as "no value" (e.g. e for empty). Or use a char?, a nullable char although I prefer the first two options.

Comment: I like the enum, let me just make sure I have it right.  I would have an enum for each fighter weight, and then at the end have enum called empty = x, and then I can do a check against that enum to see if it is set to empty, and if it does to show msgbox or something

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample implementation using the enum that was mentioned:

```
    private static WeightClass WeightClassFromRow(DataGridView gvSegments, int rowNumber)
    {
        return WeightClassFromChar(gvSegments.Rows[rowNumber].Cells[SegmentColumns.WeightClass].Value as string);
    }

    private static WeightClass WeightClassFromChar(string weightClassString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(weightClassString))
            return WeightClass.None;
        switch (weightClassString[0])
        {
            case 'H':
                return WeightClass.Heaveyweight;
            case 'L':
                return WeightClass.Lightweight;
            default:
                return WeightClass.None;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful! is this how you would do it jeffrey?

Comment: @Johnny Quest - Yes, this is how I would do it.